# 1996 Acura integra 5speed clicking noise

Tags: manual-transmission

Ok when I push in the clutch the noise goes away... It's a loud Tat tat tat....also my clutch pedal sticks almost to the floor.....it still works but the pedal is not springing back ..half way up it just feels like its not even connected..then it engages about an inch or so from the floor ??? The clutch & forks etc.$1,250 was replaced 2 yrs. ago and a new slave cylinder was put on with in the last 6 months...any ideas

Answer (score 1):

The clutch pedal sticking to the floor sounds like a leaking clutch master cylinder, clutch slave cylinder, or clutch hydraulic line. Since you replaced the slave 2 years ago, it's probably the master. Check the fluid level in the clutch master cylinder reservoir (under the hood near the bottom of the windshield on the drivers side). Refilling the reservoir (with brake fluid) may help in the short term, but you'll need to find the source of the leak as soon as possible. This problem could leave you stranded on the side of the road, so I'd figure that out immediately.

The clicking sound that goes away when you press the clutch pedal might be caused by a worn or scored pilot bushing, or it could be a more serious issue. Unfortunately, replacing this part requires the removal of the transmission, which is not an easy task. I'd get this checked by a transmission shop, but if you can live with the noise it likely won't cause any additional damage (but again, it could be a more serious problem, and you should have a transmission shop confirm this is the issue).

Good Luck!

Comment: Man u are the bomb ....I feel like it is a leak somewhere...but it doesn't seem to use fluid ..could that mean the leak is actually sucking air in not out....I did bleed it master and it helped temporally but it still ends up mushy and to the floor....I'm on unemployment that's y I haven't taken it on yet ...I seem to pay way to much for EVERYTHING I have done ......I used a bunch cord for 6 months when my slave cylinder went out "it worked great" till a concerned friend got worried". Any idea on how a leak could suck in but not loose fluid??

Comment: Usually the only way that would happen is if the reservoir runs dry, but it doesn't sound like that is the case.. Does it go to the floor as soon as you get in the car in the morning, or does it work for a while then go to the floor once the car is warm?

Comment: Exactly that it usually is OK sort of in the morning ....but after driving it , it goes to the floor ....infact the other day I lost it completely, I couldn't even change gears ....I had just gotten home so I opened the Reservoir to check the fluid and it was full as always ...2 hours later I started it and the it was OK ...still low to the floor but was up at enough to push and engage it ....since then it has been OK still clicking but so far I can shift ....thank you for helping it sounds like you totally know this car...

Comment: I did have a '96 Civic hatchback which I absolutely loved, despite having to replace the entire clutch hydrallic system! A spongy pedal when it's warm suggests you have air in the lines, which could be from an improper bleed, a faulty or improperly adjusted master cylinder, or maaaaybe a loose clamp on the bottom of the resovoir but probably the first two. How did you bleed the system?

Comment: Okay so I made a bleeder bottle and I put brake fluid in the bottom part of the bottle for the to bus so it wouldn't suck the air back in then I drained it and there was a lot of air in the line so after that I filled up the reservoir again pumped it a little bit cuz I didn't have anyone to help me so I didn't want to empty the reservoir and get air in there again so then when the reservoir was still still had fluid in it I went ahead and filled it up again before it got it before it went down into the line and pumped it again then it worked for a little bit couple days

Comment: So it very well could have been the way I bled it but I didn't have anyone to help me cuz it's too darn hot here to have somebody stand out in the heat and try to do that LOL but everything you're saying really sounds more like what I hope it is except for the bad hydraulic system

Comment: Yeah, you'll definitely need someone to help you. One person needs to pump the pedal a few times, then hold it to the floor while the other person opens and closes the valve on the slave. Once the valve is closed, the person in the car pumps again a few times, holds, etc until no bubbles come out. You could get a vacuum bleeder but those are about as much as paying a shop to bleed it. I think you'll have to find a second person!

Comment: Cool I will cross my fingers that this will fix it ...I